# separate 1 string into more

Tags: string, r, character

Dear All,
A have a string like this:

```
a <- "Good,Good*********,Good***********,Perfect,Perfect**********,Perfect***********"
```

now I want to separate this into this:

```
a <- c("Good","Good*********","Good***********","Perfect","Perfect**********","Perfect***********")
```

any suggestions are very welcome! Thanks you,

Lisanne

Answer (score 7):

`strsplit` does this:

```
a<-"Good,Good***,Good****,Perfect,Perfect***,Perfect*****"
a <- strsplit(a, ",")[[1]]
```

Comment: And now I want to combine the results in the C() function to combine the arguments.

Comment: Combine how? The result of a I pasted above is exactly equivalent to what you specified as your desired output (to test, load your desired output and check the results of a==b).

Comment: Just curious: what does [[1]] do?

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is a perfect candidate for `scan`:

```
scan(text = a, what = "", sep = ",")
# Read 6 items
# [1] "Good"               "Good*********"      "Good***********"    "Perfect"   
# [5] "Perfect**********"  "Perfect***********"
```